# Given $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $\int_{0}^{1} f^2(x)dx=1$, evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} xf(x)f'(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals, contest-math

> Q.Suppose $f$ is a real valued continuously differentiable function on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $$\int_{0}^{1} f^2(x)dx=1.$$ Find the value of $\int_{0}^{1} xf(x)f'(x)dx$?

**My approach :**

Let $I(x)$ be the antiderivative of $xf(x)f'(x)$ and $G(x)$ be the antiderivative of $f^2(x)$, here $f^2(x) = (f(x))^2$. We want to calculate $I(1)-I(0)$ and we know that $G(1)-G(0)=1.$

Then using integration by parts, 
$$\begin{align}
I(x)&=xf(x)\int f'(x)dx-\int \left(\int f'(x)dx\right)\left(\frac {d}{dx} xf(x)\right)dx \\
&=xf^2(x)-\int f(x)(xf'(x)+f(x))dx\\
&=xf^2(x)-I(x)-\int f^2(x)dx \\
\Rightarrow 2I(x)&=xf^2(x)-\int f^2(x)dx \\
\Rightarrow I(x)&=\frac {xf^2(x)-\int f^2(x)dx}2\\
&=\frac {xf^2(x)-G(x)}2.
\end{align}$$

$\displaystyle \therefore I(1)-I(0)=\frac {1f^2(1)-G(1)}2 - \frac {0f^2(0)-G(0)}2=-\frac {G(1)-G(0)}2=-\frac 12.$

---

In my approach above, I didn't apply hypothesis $f(0)=0$ anywhere. I didn't understand where I used the given fact that $f$ is a continuously differentiable function on $[0,1]$. So I feel that my solution is ambiguous.

1. What are errors in my proof?
2. Can the two hypotheses which I mentioned be dropped safely?

Comment: The answer is indeed $- \frac 1 2$ and f(0) is not needed. But you can simplify your argument by writing $f(x)f'(x)$ as $ \frac 1 2 \{f^{2}\}'$ and then integrating by parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hypothesis on $f(0)$ is unnecessary here. Also note that we only need $f$ to be differentiable with integrable derivative, so $C^1$ is definitely not necessary, but sufficient as any continuous function on $[0,1]$ is integrable on $[0,1]$. Put $I = \int_0^1xf(x)f'(x)\,dx$. By integration by parts,
\begin{align*}
I &= xf(x)^2\bigg|_0^1 - \int_0^1f(x)[f(x) + xf'(x)]\,dx \\
&= f(1) - \int_0^1 f(x)^2\,dx - \int_0^1xf(x)f'(x)\,dx \\
&= -1- I.
\end{align*}
Hence $2I = -1$, so $I = -1/2$.

Another way to do this integral is to notice that, by the Chain Rule, $f(x)f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}\big(f(x)^2\big)'$. Integrating by parts,
\begin{align*}
I = \frac{1}{2}\bigg[xf(x)^2\bigg|_0^1 - \int_0^1f(x)^2\,dx\bigg] = \frac{1}{2}[0 - 1] = -\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Small mistake: OP said $ f(1)=0 $, not $ f(1)=1 $.

Comment: @Bib-lost, in the OP's post, it's written $f(1) = 1$, but maybe the OP meant $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. I never make such mistakes usually in my posts. I've edited my OP now. I meant $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Again forgive me for you have really put your efforts and I fully appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = f^2(x)$, $dv = dx$ then we can perform integration by parts on the original integral

$$ \int_0^1 f^2(x)\ dx = x\ f^2(x) \bigg|_0^1 - \int_0^1 x (2f(x) f'(x))\ dx = 1  $$

Thus 
$$  \int_0^1 xf(x)f'(x)\ dx = \frac{1}{2}\left(x\ f^2(x) \bigg|_0^1 -1\right) $$

The function values are inconsistent in your post title and question. If $f(1) = 1$ than the answer is $0$, if $f(1)=0$ then it's $-1/2$. In either case the value of $f(0)$ is unimportant.

Comment: Dear Dylan, I'm extremely sorry for causing confusion in my title and OP. I've edited OP now. I meant $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Your efforts are very much appreciated!